setup vpn connection using nmcli - Connection activation failed: No valid secrets
I'm trying to configure an openconnect VPN connection in nmcli on a Debian 12 running SwayWM. I manage to connect to the vpn using nmcli with the --ask flag but it cannot read vpn secrets provided with the configuration file below. Any idea?
[connection]
id=VPN
uuid=d9133c7c-1c0e-47dc-8da1-9e52eced6385
type=vpn
autoconnect=false
timestamp=1726496682

[vpn]
authgroup=Personels
authtype=password
autoconnect-flags=0
certsigs-flags=0
cookie-flags=2
enable_csd_trojan=no
gateway=vpn.grenet.fr
gateway-flags=2
gwcert-flags=2
lasthost-flags=0
password-flags=0
pem_passphrase_fsid=no
prevent_invalid_cert=no
protocol=anyconnect
resolve-flags=2
stoken_source=disabled
user-name=myusername
xmlconfig-flags=0
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openconnect

[vpn-secrets]
#form:main:group_list=TunnelGroup_Personnels
#form:main:username=myusername
password=mypassword

I tried nmcli con reload, systemctl restart NetworkManager. I also tried using 'passwd-file' without success.
Also journalctl logs :

  [1726513110.5164]
vpn[0x55c2cb4b6330,d9133c7c-1c0e-47dc-8da1-9e52eced6385,"VPN"]:
secrets: failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were av> lines
751-800/800 (END)

Duplicate unanswered posts :

https://serverfault.com/questions/816714/how-do-i-supply-a-password-to-networkmanager-openconnect-automatically
How to set a VPN connection in nmcli?

